# Implode an array to dayname

Tags: php, implode

I am imploding an array in php like this `implode(', ',$array)` that will return `7, 3, 4` (number of dayname)

How can I change that to `Sunday, Wednesday, Thursday`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply initialize an `$array` like this and it will be easy to get name format of the day,

```
<?php
$days = [
  1 => 'Sunday',
  2 => 'Monday',
  3 => 'Tuesday',
  4 => 'Wednesday',
  5 => 'Thursday',
  6 => 'Friday',
  7 => 'Saturday'
];
$array = [7,3,4];
$result = array_map(function ($a)  use($days) { return $days[$a]; }, $array);
echo implode(',', $result);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/9Zb5M

Answer (score 1):

If you've got the calendar extension enabled (which I think most installations probably will), you can use the [`jddayofweek`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.jddayofweek.php) function to convert directly between a number and a day name. The indexes are zero-based from Monday, so you'd need to subtract one from your array:

```
$i = 7;
echo jddayofweek($i - 1, 1);
# Sunday
```

You can wrap this up with `array_map` to convert the entire array:

```
$dayNames = array_map(function ($e) {
    return jddayofweek($e - 1, 1);
}, $dayNumbers);
```

Full demo here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/957ab0a38d6055ca1ffb37e5623dc7487a58cef4